# Dynamically adding ng-pattern, missing validation classes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove, from a directive, the "ng-pattern" attribute. Here's my directive:

```
ap.directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: { test: "=myDirective" },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('test', function () {
                if (someCondition) {
                    element.removeAttr("ng-pattern");
                } else {
                    element.attr("ng-pattern", "/^([0-9]{5})$|^([0-9]{9})$/");
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And the input tag from the html:

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
    <input name="test" required class="form-control" ng-model="myModel" my-    directive="someValueFromScope"/>
</form>
```

If I inspect the DOM elements from Chrome dev tools, the "ng-pattern" attribute is added to the input tag, but the validation classes (ng-invalid-pattern or ng-valid-pattern) are not added. If I add the "ng-pattern" directly from the html, everything works as expected.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to set a blank pattern instead of removing `ngPattern`. DOM manipulation in AngularJS is seldom a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, compiling the parent scope did the trick.

```
$compile(element)($scope.$parent)
```

Comment: I am struck with the infinite loop still after keeping $parent. Can you provide me an example code in jsfiddle or plunker or any explanation is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use $compile and $set for this like :-

```
attrs.$set("ng-pattern", "/^([0-9]{5})$|^([0-9]{9})$/");
$compile(element)($scope);
```

Comment: Thank for replying. Do you mean $compile(element)($scope);?

Comment: No, it's not working. I added what you suggested and an extra "console.log("scope:", $scope);" and this gets logged over and over in the console, like it's some infinite loop somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

instead of $watch use $observe method

```
attrs.$observe('test', function () {
      //do something
});
```